# simple ref vs lightweight tags in git

Tags: git, tags, ref

i'm currently try to understand internal of git; my question is what is the difference between a lightweight tag and a simple ref ?
based on what i've read so far, a **lightweight tag** is actually a file with name of the tag and its content is an object-id [a commit-object id i guess?].in this book 'git pocket guide', the author said "a **simple ref** points directly to an object-id"; that's where i'm confused! in my opinion these are same things but named differently.
is it correct to say that a lightweight-tag is a specific version of a simple ref? because lightweight tag only can points to commit-objects but simple ref isn't limited to commits only.

Comment: Does the author give examples of `a simple ref`?

Comment: @ElpieKay yes; 
refs/tags/ and refs/heads/, to hold the names of tags and local branches, respectively. git references are in these directories [symbolic or simple].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *ref* (or the longer variant, *reference* ) is a name, in Git.  There are many forms of references:

- `refs/heads/xyz` is the *branch name* `xyz`;
- `refs/tags/xyz` is the *tag name* `xyz`;
- `refs/remotes/origin/xyz` is the *remote-tracking name* that your Git is using for a branch named `xyz` as seen in some other Git repository you're calling `origin`;

and so on.

A Git *object* is one of four object types:

- a *blob object* holds data (file contents or the target of a symbolic link, for instance);
- a *tree object* holds <mode, name, hash> tuples in it, where the *mode* tells you what kind of Git object the *hash* specifies and the *name* contains a name component (directory or file name);
- a *commit object* holds the metadata of a commit, which must contain specific headers (including exactly one `tree` line giving the hash ID of one tree object: this is the commit's snapshot); and
- a *tag object* or *annotated tag object* contains the tag data, which—like a commit—must contain specific headers, including an `object` line giving the hash ID of the tagged object (which may be any of the four object types, including another annotated tag).

All objects have a unique hash ID.  This hash ID acts as the key in a simple [key-value database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database).  Git will use the key to find the object; you must provide the key (somehow).  If you provide a shortened key—i.e., a prefix of a key—Git will look up all objects found by that prefix; if only one is found, that's assumed to be the correct full hash ID, and we proceed from there; if more than one is found, we have an ambiguous hash ID (it could be any of those).

All refs must contain the hash ID of some existing, valid object.  Some objects also contain hash IDs; these too must be hash IDs of some existing, valid object.<sup>1</sup>

Some refs are constrained as to which object types they may contain: in particular, branch names must contain commit hash IDs.  Since a remote-tracking name is created by reading a branch name from some other Git repository (which should obey this same set of constraints), a remote-tracking name should also contain a commit hash ID.  Tag names, however, can contain the hash ID of any of the four internal object types.

A *lightweight tag* is a ref of the form `refs/tags/*`—hence a tag name—that contains a valid hash ID, but one that is for an internal Git object that is *not* an tag object.  An *annotated tag* is a ref of the form `refs/tags/*` that contains a valid hash ID for an object that is an annotated tag object.

> is it correct to say that a lightweight-tag is a specific version of a simple ref?

Mostly, yes.  A lightweight tag is a specific ref: one that starts with `refs/tags` (and then a slash and more name characters).  However, it meets one more constraint: the hash ID stored *in* that ref is that of an object whose types is not "annotated tag".

---

<sup>1</sup>This constraint is relaxed a bit in a so-called *shallow* or *partial clone*.  (You can have a clone that is both shallow and partial.)  The hash ID should be valid, but we can't tell whether it is until we fill in the missing objects.

Answer (score 1):

You are right : a lightweight tag *is* a simple ref.

Its main specificity is that it is stored under `.git/refs/tags`, and that's a convention which indicates that git commands can treat it like a tag :

- `git tag --list` will list it,
- `git tag -d <tag_name>` will delete it,
- `git` will shorten the name `refs/tags/tag_name` to `tag_name` in several cases,
- etc ...

---

The other main conventions related to refs are :

- branches are stored under `refs/heads`
- remote references (or remote branches) are stored under `refs/remotes/<remote_name>/`

and these references are simple refs too.

---

An example of a non simple ref is `HEAD` (stored in `.git/HEAD`).

You can run `cat .git/HEAD` to view its content : if you currently are on a branch, you should see somthing like :

```
$ cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/my_branch
```

This is called a *symbolic ref*, and commands that act on `HEAD` (for example : `git log HEAD`) will "translate" `HEAD` to `my_branch`.